# Big O notation in practice

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

if $P_{n}$ is the $n$'th prime I have that for a constant $a$ $$n\geq \frac{aP_{n}}{\log(P_{n})}$$

and it implies that $$\log(P_{n})=O(\log(n))$$

I'm unsure of how this is implied and where the $\log(n)$ has come from.

Comment: A marker might dock you a mark for forgetting to mention that $a>0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply take the natural log of both sides of the inequality to get

$$\log(n)\geq \log\left(\frac{a P_n}{\log{P_n}}\right)=\log(a)+\log(P_n)-\log(\log(P_n))$$

Since $\log(\log(P_n))$ grows much slower than $\log(P_n)$, for large enough $n$

$$\log(a)+\log(P_n)-\log(\log(P_n))>\frac{1}{2}\log(P_n)$$

We conclude there exists a constant $c$ such that

$$\log(n)>c\log(P_n)$$

Thus

$$\log(P_n)=O(\log(n))$$

Comment: +1/ You should say there exists $c>0$ such that $\log (n)>c\log (P_n)$ for all sufficiently large $n.$

Comment: My edit was for a typo  $P_N$ in the 2nd-last line.

Answer (score 1):

From your inequality and the monotonicity of the logarithm, 
$$ \log n \geq \log(P_n) + \log(a) - \log \log(P_n) \text{.}  $$
Once $P_n$ is large enough that $\log \log P_n > 0$, the right-hand side is $ > \log(P_n) + \log(a)$.  Now you have 
$$ \log n \geq \log(P_n) + \log(a)  \text{,}  $$
which is sufficient to show that $\log n$ is greater than or equal to a constant multiple of $\log(P_n)$ for all $n$.  (For instance any constant $\geq 2$ works once $P_n > a$.)

---

Another method.  After taking logs, factor out the (given or recognized) leading term.
$$  \log n \geq \log(P_n) \left( 1 + \frac{\log{a}}{\log P_n} - \frac{\log\log P_n}{\log P_n} \right)  \text{.}  $$
Set 
$$ c(x) =  1 + \frac{\log{a}}{\log x} - \frac{\log\log x}{\log x}  \text{.}  $$
We can check that we have the correct leading order term factored out.  Set $L = | \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} c(x)|$.  If $L = 0$, the factored term grows too quickly.  If $L$ is finite, the correct leading term has been factored out.  If $L$ diverges to $\infty$, the factored term grows too slowly.  If $L$ is not a positive, finite number, go back and factor out the correct leading term.  Here we don't need the absolute values (because everything is positive for large $n$) and we find \begin{align*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} c(x) &=  \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(1 + \frac{\log{a}}{\log x} - \frac{\log\log x}{\log x} \right)   \\
  &= 1 + 0 - 0  \\
  &= 1  \text{.}
\end{align*}
So $\log P_n$ is the correct leading term.  Now two ways to finish:

1. For any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is an $n_0$ such that for all $n > n_0$, $c(n) < 1 + \varepsilon$ (directly from the definition of limit), so $\log n \geq (1+\varepsilon)\log P_n$ for $n > n_0$, showing $\log P_n \in O(\log n)$.
2. $\max_{x \in [1,\infty)} c(x) = 1-\frac{1}{a \mathrm{e}}$ (assuming natural logs, although a different base of logarithm just changes the details of this constant, not that it is a constant).  So $\log n \geq (1-\frac{1}{a \mathrm{e}})\log P_n$ for all $n$, showing $\log P_n \in O(\log n)$.

In the one case, we show that there is a tail for any constant $> 1$, which is what is in the definition of Big-O.  In the second, we are lucky enough that there is a universal constant that works for all $n \geq 1$.

---

Finally, a third way.  After taking logs, notice 
$$  \log n - \log a \geq \log P_n - \log \log P_n \text{.}  $$
Also, \begin{align*}
\log n &\in O(\log n)  \text{,}  \\
\log a &\in O(\log n) \text{, and }  \\
\log \log P_n &\in O(\log P_n)  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Therefore, 
\begin{align*}
\log P_n - \log \log P_n &\in O(\log P_n)  \\
&\subseteq O(\log n + \log a)  \\
&\subseteq O(\log n) + O(\log n)  \\
&= O(\log n)  \text{.}  
\end{align*}

This says there are $n_1$ and $n_2$ as well as $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that for all $n > \max\{n_1, n_2\}$, 
$$  c_1 \log n \geq c_2 \log P_n  \text{.}  $$
But this says 
$$  \log n \geq \frac{c_2}{c_1} \log P_n  $$
for $n$ sufficiently large, so $\log P_n \in O(\log n)$.